# Passing variable to form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am passing the agent id through to my forms.  Question is, how do I take that agent id, grab the id, then make the dropdown field default selection the agent id that I passed through?

Passing the variable

```
<input type="button" name="chargeback" value="Submit Chargeback" href="{% url commissions-chargebacks_insert agent.id %}" />
```

My views.py

```
def insert(request, agent=None, investment=None, chargeback=None, *args, **kwargs):
from commissions.forms import ChargebackForm
context = {}
selected_agent_id = kwargs['agent_id']
if request.POST:
    form = ChargebackForm(selected_agent_id, request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        chargeback = form.save(commit=False)
        chargeback.total_branch_commission = str(float("-0%s" % chargeback.amount))
        chargeback.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('commissions-chargebacks_browse'))
    else:
        request.user.message_set.create(message='Please correct errors and try submitting again.')
else:
    form = ChargebackForm(selected_agent_id)

context['form'] = form
return render_to_response('commissions/admin/chargebacks/insert.html', RequestContext(request, context))
```

forms.py

```
class ChargebackForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, selected_agent_id, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ChargebackForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['agent'].queryset = Agent.objects.all().filter(agent_id = selected_agent_id)

class Meta:
    model = Chargeback

    fields = ('agent', 'amount','description','policy_num')
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean by passing the agent id through to your forms, and where in views.py do you want to use it? It seems that in both these pieces of code you have access to the agent id (it is an argument to the `insert` view and it appears to be in the template context) so I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: can you not just do `context['agent']` in the views, and access it in the `template`?

Comment: edited for clarification

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 1.4, you can use the [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets-initial-data) parameter on `ChargebackForm` in your view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ChargebackForm(
        selected_agent_id, request.POST, initial={'agent':selected_agent_id})
else:
    form = ChargebackForm(selected_agent_id, initial={'agent':selected_agent_id})
```